# Packet receiving in pthreads raw sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I am doing a port scanner program as part of a school project where am using raw sockets. My understanding is this:

When using multithreading with raw sockets, each pthread does NOT get a copy of the packets seen by the NIC. Hence to handle all the different thread, I would need a receiving thread that passes messages to the correct thread.

Is this correct?

EDIT : My hypothesis is, the OS sends the packet only once to the process. If the wrong pthread was receiving the packet, the packet could be missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want to receive the packets in all threads, you just need to create a separate raw socket (with the same arguments) in each thread.  I haven't found a good resource describing this on Linux, but that's how it's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows:

> if several SOCK_RAW sockets are open on a computer at the same time,
>   the same datagrams may be delivered to all the open sockets